# Using Conditionals

Tags: conditional-constructions

To complete the following sentence with a suitable form of the verb in bracket, I used ***past perfect*** *(hadn't come)*,** but the answer key says the correct tense is ***past simple*** *(didn't come)*.**

I cannot understand why. Can you provide me with an explanation, please?

> " If you ___________ to class yesterday, you won't know about the exam. "

Comment: As written the sentence makes no sense.  There's no way to match up the conditional with the simple future *won't*.   "Didn't come" is no better than "hadn't come".   Is this from a source written by a native speaker?

Comment: @Andrew - I disagree that the sentence doesn't make sense.  It makes sense if it's addressed to the "impersonal you" as a general principle (not to the specific "you" of the listener). It has the same construction as "If you didn't buy a ticket, you won't win the lottery."

Comment: @Andrew - It's from "New English File" published by Oxford. Advanced level.

Comment: @CanadianYankee  Do people really say that, though?  I would have said, *"If you **didn't** buy a ticket, how **can you expect** to win?"*  Either that or I would use the present tense:  *"If you **don't** buy a ticket, you **won't** win"*.  Mixing up tenses like that seems very awkward.

Comment: @CanadianYankee  Although I see how the writer might want to express a *causal* relationship -- in which case I would use "since":  *"**Since** you didn't go to class yesterday, you won't know about the exam"*.

Comment: @Andrew The sentence seems fine to me as well. If [past condition] then [future consequence]. Your "... how can you expect to win" is a better edit, but I don't see anything wrong with the mixed tenses.

Comment: Consider "If you didn't clean your room yesterday, you won't be able to go to the party tomorrow." The parent doesn't know whether the child has cleaned the room, which either did or did not happen in the past, but the ability to go to the party will happen in the future, after the parent audits the room.

Comment: @Tashus  It must be my vernacular then, as your sentence sounds equally awkward to me.   Grammatically I guess it's fine, but semantically it sounds like it's sending mixed signals, as the "won't" implies there is still some *possibility*.  Otherwise I would definitely say, *"If you **didn't clean** your room, you **aren't going**"*, or I would leave the door open, *"If you **don't** clean your room, you **won't** go"

Comment: @Andrew Yeah, it could be regional conventions or something. To me, "you won't go" and "you aren't going" are completely equivalent, and I do think there is some possibility, at least with respect to the speaker. The child knows whether or not they cleaned their room, so whether they go to the party is already determined, but the parent does not know, so there *is* some possibility either way, from their perspective.

Answer (score 1):

> If you didn't come to class yesterday, you won't know about the exam.

All the modal verbs have various meanings in various contexts, and the variety of conditional constructions is much greater than is usually taught; so without context a sentence like this offers many opportunities for confusion. You have to sort of work your way back from the forms to the implied context for it to make sense.

1. One very reliable "rule" for conditional constructions is that both the condition clause (the subordinate *if* clause or *protasis*) and the consequence clause (the main *then* clause or *apodosis*) must express the same order of "reality": that is, both must be either real or unreal. In this case *won't know* is unambiguously real (the unreal form would be *wouldn't know*), so *didn't go* must be real as well.

   Note that this excludes *If you hadn't gone ...*, since that always implies a "condition contrary to fact"—an unreal condition.
2. Another consideration here is that *will* (or, as here, *won't*) has other meanings than just marking future tense. There's a pretty strong indication that *you won't know ...* is a simple prediction: obviously you *will* know *something* about the exam from the very fact that I'm mentioning it! The likeliest meaning here is the "deictic" sense of *will*: a fairly certain present-tense inference that such-and-such is a fact, as in

   > **A:** Who's that at the door?
   >   **B:** Oh, that **will be** John—he said he was coming over.
3. There are other considerations in play here, such as the difference between "actualization" and "inference" conditionals (this is an "inference" conditional, in which the condition can actually follow its consequence) and the distinction between "open" and "closed" conditions (this is a "closed" condition, one which is accepted as true), but you don't really need these to understand this sentence. To paraphrase it:

   > Since (I noticed *or* you tell me that) you didn't come to class yesterday, I assume you don't know about the exam. *which implies, one hopes, that the speaker will continue* Let me tell you what you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

The correct form is

"If you didn't go to class yesterday, you wouldn't know about the exam."

However, especially in speech, even native speakers can be casual about sequence of tenses so you may well hear

"If you didn't go to class yesterday, you don't/won't/can't know about the exam."

American English is in flux about conditionals and subjunctives.

Comment: Is this a particularly AmEng phenomenon?

Comment: I am not very conversant with English outside the US. What I can say is that **in the US** the traditional rules of formal English with respect to conditionals, subjunctives, and sequence of tenses are frequently no longer followed.

Comment: I would find this use of *didn't go* as implicitly unreal bizarre: grammatically defensible, perhaps, but not idiomatic in any register.

Comment: @StoneyB I did not say that I would use it or that I find it attractive. I said that formations like this are common in the US, even among educated people. I know: they grate on my ear all too frequently.

Comment: I was speaking of what you offer as the "correct" version.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the following point while I was studying the *IF* section in Michael Swan’s *Practical English Usage*. I think it will help us all.

If: ordinary structures

When we are not talking about ‘unreal’ situations, we use the same tenses with *if* as with other conjunctions. Present tenses are used to refer to the present, past tenses to the past, and so on. Compare:

***If*** you ***didn’t study*** physics at school, you ***won’t understand*** this book.

***Because*** you ***didn't study*** physics at school, you ***won’t understand*** this book.

I believe this further clarifies what has been discussed here. Am I right?